# Loading an NPM package using Chef

Tags: npm, chef-infra

I'm new to Chef and followed this tutorial (http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/06/chef-solo-tutorial-managing-a-single-server-with-chef/) in which I created 4 files: install.sh, solo.json, solo.rb and default.rb. (default.rb is under the directory coobooks/zombie/recipes/ and all other files are under a top level chef directory). I ran the install.sh script which basically installs ruby and chef and then issues "chef-solo -c solo.rb -j solo.json" but got this error:

**"ERROR: Cookbook npm not found. If you're loading npm from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata."**

I think I'm incorrectly referencing the npm package or including a particular node package (Mocha) the wrong way. Can anyone please give me any guidance on this error? Thanks.

---

My default.rb file:

```
package 'nodejs'
package 'npm'

include_recipe "npm"

npm_package "default" do
  enable true
end

npm_package "mocha@1.17.1"
```

---

My solo.json file:

```
{
    "run_list": [ "recipe[npm]", "recipe[zombie::default]" ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to an the npm cookbook to the `cookbooks/` directory. You can grab it from [here](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/npm)

Btw, that tutorial is great, helps lay down a lot of the fundamental understanding of the chef ecosystem.

Comment: I agree that it's a good link, but it's very dated now. For a more modern interpretation in using chef solo, lookup the knife-solo project: http://matschaffer.github.io/knife-solo/ It incorporates modern tools like Berkshelf for managing cookbook dependencies. And finally Chef solo is starting to fall out of favour. Chef 11 has released a new "local mode" style of operation (leveraging chef-zero an embedded chef server): http://www.getchef.com/blog/2013/10/31/chef-client-z-from-zero-to-chef-in-8-5-seconds/

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Do you mean download and unzip each cookbook from http://community.opscode.com/ and save the tree under my /cookbooks directory? If so, does that mean every machine/user that will be running my script then has to checkout all these cookbook files on their machine?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right. To Mark's point knife-solo is a "poor mans" chef server. chef-solo is/was created for provisioning one machine at a time.

Comment: If you want to take it one step farther, I created https://github.com/jjasghar/provision_mac to show how to use chef-solo to provision a mac, with the basis of that tutorial.

Comment: @JJAsghar nice error message `You need to install chef dumb-dumb` lol!